# the verb "besiege"

Tags: meaning-in-context

If a city was besieged, does it mean that it surrendered and was captured or it did not necessarily surrender and wasn't captured?

Comment: The siege is the battle, not the outcome of the battle. If the siege is lifted, the city was besieged, but did not surrender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "besiege" has nothing to do with "capture."

A city or forteress can be captured without having been besieged, e.g., by betrayal, surprise, negligence, or assault, and a city or fortress can be besieged, with the result being either surrender or freedom.

A siege is the isolation, either partial or total, of a place with the purpose of inducing surrender. It usually also includes operations that reduce the capacity of the place to defend itself. In a classic siege, the primary inducement to surrender was the combination of starvation and systematic impairment of the place's defenses. The last great siege in western history was the unsuccessful one of Leningrad, which lasted over 800 days.

In European warfare during the late 17th through 19th centuries, sieges were **usually** conducted according to certain generally accepted conventions. Those commanding the besieged could not "honorably" surrender while enough defenders still lived unwounded and had food, water, arms, and reasonably effective fortifications. (Commanders who surrendered "dishonorably" were subject to execution by their own side.) A place that surrendered before a successful attack was given very lenient treatment: the defenders were allowed to leave with their freedom, lives, and personal arms, and the non-combatants were protected by law from robbery, rape, and murder. If, however, the place did not surrender and was successfully attacked, the people in that place, combatants and non-combatants, men, women, and children, were given up to "sack," which essentially meant that the invaders were free to rob, rape, torture, and murder without restraint or any future criminal liability for at least one day, sometimes as many as three. This was considered (and probably was) a great improvement over the preceding treatment of conquered places. The conventions provided incentives to defending commanders to resist while rescue was imaginable and incentives to commanders on both sides to minimize deaths among combatants of both sides and prevent permanent harm to non-combatants.

PS: This is off topic. One of the violators of the understanding about sieges was Napoleon Bonaparte, who had several thousand defending soldiers executed two days after the surrender of Jaffa. His next siege at Acre was unsuccessful: there is little incentive to surrender if you will almost certainly be executed by your captors. Technically Bonaparte may have been "in the right" because mercy after surrender was a European custom not recognized elsewhere and because Jaffa itself had been taken by assault. But as Talleyrand said to Napoleon on a different topic, a blunder can be worse than a crime.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say the two have "nothing to do with each other". A siege may very well lead to the capture of a city or fort, and presumably the purpose of a siege is to capture the place. But I think you mean, a place can be besieged without being captured (if they withstand the siege), and a place can be capture without be besieged (by various means such as those you listed).

Comment: While this answer contains some interesting information, the bulk of the last three paragraphs are not relevant to the question or to the English language. I would recommend cutting them.

Comment: @Jay "Attempt" does not mean "succeed." The words express entirely different concepts as do "purpose" and "means."  A siege is one of several means to attempt the purpose of capture. I feel the second paragraph in my answer mirrors your comment fairly closely. I am not sure what you think needs to be added to that paragraph, but I am open to expanding it.